# How to reload the data that will be displayed on one view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, reload, subview

One view that is a subview of one view controller. And this view will show some data that are stored on one plist file. However, this plist file will be changed on next view controller. When the screen back from next view controller to previous view controller that has the customary view as subview, the data will not be refreshed. In this situation, how can I fix it? And there are *several solutions* that are provided on the network.

**First solution:**

```
if(self isViewLoaded)
{
    self.view = nil;
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

This solution has one problem that the view of controller is black and will not show any others. But if I delete following code, the data on the view could be refreshed.

```
self.view = nil;
```

However, there is one problem that I could see some words under this layer. I guess that it will create new layer above the older layer. Because some lighter words that are not the data on current version plist file instead of previous version plist file are on this subview

**Second solution:**

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

this code has not any function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter postNotifcation from your "next view controller".

E.g:

```
-(void)updatePLISTData
{
    // code to download new data for PLIST

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNamed:@"notif_plistChanged" .... object:thePlistObject ];
}
```

Make sure you remember to add an observer to your "parent view controller" that pushed your "next view controller".

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatePlist:) object:nil];
```

and also to remove the observer

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Once you received your notification, the notification will invoke whatever method you specified when you add observer. In this case, you have

```
-(void)updatePlist:(NSNofitication *)paramPlist
{
    self.plist = paramPlist;
}
```